# How to merge theses 2 lines of jQuery in one?

Tags: jquery

How can I merge these 2 lines into only one ?

```
jQuery(".my-class").children(".open").show();
jQuery(".my-class").children(".closed").hide();
```

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you need to merge them together?

Comment: shorter code is not always better. this one is more clear and easier to understand. If you want one line, make it a function and call it each time you need it.

Comment: you need something like this http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 1):

Just in case what you need is to toggle this elements visibility (alternate depending on a button click, or something like that), you could use...

```
$('.my-class').children('.open,.closed').toggle()
```

... but if you just want to show `.open` and hide `.closed`, your code looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.
The reason was that sometimes jQuery(".my-class") can be very long (if we have a complicated search using parent() or what over).

I think I have found a good solution :

```
jQuery(".my-class").each(function(){
  jQuery(this).children(".open").show();
  jQuery(this).children(".closed").hide();
})
```

Toggle is a good option to, but my question was more generic, not only for .show() or .hide()

Comment: Also, you can always compute it once and save it in a variable which you then use multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `end()` method

Try this one:

```
jQuery(".my-class").children(".open").show().end().children(".closed").hide();
```